# Box contains different balls formulation

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

There is a box of size $100mm \times 120mm \times 60 mm$ and five different balls, each ball has a radius and values as below:

Balls   $\quad$ A  B C D E
Radius  $10$ $15$ $20$ $25$ $22$
Value $\quad$ $20$ $60$ $70$ $110$ $100$

Provide a non-linear programming so that the total value of packed balls is maximized？ The constraints should only contain quandratic formulations.

I really have no idea how to develop the constraints... hope someone can give me a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Why don't you take the ratio between the volume and the value? That would maximize "Points per Space"

Comment: Thank you, but I still have trouble developing the constraints, can you make it clear?